# VBA SumProduct Runtime Error 13

Tags: vba, runtime-error

As a part of a much longer code, I am trying to include a SumProduct

```
Dim SumPr as Variant

SumPr=Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(((Workbooks(Source2).Sheets("Prices_EUR_Adj").Range("A:A")) = Range("A" & i)) * ((Workbooks(Source2).Sheets("Prices_EUR_Adj").Range("D:D")) = "PH") * (Workbooks(Source2).Sheets("Prices_EUR_Adj").Range(ColLtr & ":" & ColLtr)))
MsgBox SumPr
```

However, I keep getting Runtime Error 13 for some reason. Any idea what is wrong? Source2 is properly defined, and ColLtr is letter conversion of column number I got from match; it also works ok as checked by message box.

Comment: Have you tried writing the `SUMPRODUCT` formula in your worksheet first to check that the formula works?

Comment: Yes, I actually first recorded the formula and then I rewrote it as I need relative reference in the last column (before the vlookup, I search for the number of column with match function and the convert it to letter denotation of the column)...

Comment: What do you mean when you say it works ok as checked by message box?

Comment: - That it gives me the value it should, e.g. "MB" (plus the code is taken from somewhere on this forum and it worked for the person)

Comment: So where are you getting the error?

Comment: Basically, all of the parts seem to be working on their own but as soon as I run the "entire" vlookup, the vlookup line turns yellow with error 13...

Comment: By "vlookup" do you mean your `SumPr=...` line?

Comment: Sorry, just writing vlookup in different part :) Yes, I mean the sumproduct function

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error, but I'm not sure I'm understanding what the result should be. What do you expect to get for `SumPr`?

Comment: Okay, so: in two columns, i have some sort of identificators in the original file. I am going line by line and search in a different file for a line with these identificators. (the first two parts of sumproduct) Then I am multiplying it with the third section which is column with prices (must be dynamic because each column represents a different date, its number is identified by previous match). Basically, i was able to record the non-dynamic version (which worked perfectly) in R1C1 format but needed to rewrite it from it (="=vlookup(...) ) as I need to add the dynamic property...

Comment: So the result is basically price which is to be stored into a variable/inserted into a certain cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `Evaluate` function instead:

```
Dim SumPr As Variant

SumPr = Application.Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(" & Workbooks(Source2).Sheets("Prices_EUR_Adj").Range("A:A").Address & "=" & Range("A" & i).Address & ")," & _
                                        "--(" & Workbooks(Source2).Sheets("Prices_EUR_Adj").Range("D:D").Address & "=""PH"")," & _
                                        Workbooks(Source2).Sheets("Prices_EUR_Adj").Range(ColLtr & ":" & ColLtr).Address & ")")
MsgBox SumPr
```

I'm sure the `WorksheetFunction.SumProduct` will also work, but I was able to get the `Evaluate` function working easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works this way... Btw, what is the difference between WorksheetFunction and Evaluate?

Comment: Glad I could help! There really is no difference between the two functions. In my opinion, `Evaluate` is just easier to use when copying functions directly off of a worksheet.